# Elasticsearch term aggregation using script with key as integer

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

Is it possible to make the `key` of the resulting aggregation be the `int` value returned by the script instead of a `string`?

See [this example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#_use_of_a_script_to_aggregate_by_day_of_the_week), but using `dayOfMonth` or `hourOfDay` instead of `dayOfWeek`, so there are more than 10 values, so the result ends up being ordered, `"1", "10", "11", ..." instead of`1, 2, 3,...`.

Here's an example of the full call:

```
POST /sales/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs": {
        "dayOfMonth": {
            "terms": {
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "source": "doc['date'].value.dayOfMonth"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And an example response:

```
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "dayOfWeek": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "10",
          "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can instruct your client app to make the conversion, can't you?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer that that not be required and the result come back sorted numerically instead of alphabetically.

Comment: The values are "1" through "7". How will that be sorted differently than 1 through 7?

Comment: `dayOfMonth` or `hourOfDay` are better examples that demonstrate the problem. I've update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `value_type` parameter can resolve the issue by coercing the unmapped field into the correct type.

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "ip_addresses": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['date'].value.dayOfMonth",
        "value_type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> [Failed Trying to Format Bytesedit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_failed_trying_to_format_bytes)